# Reading data from JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a datra structure like this:

```
"37_7009": [
    {
        "viewport_dimensions": {"width": 1583, "height": 798}, 
        "mouse_position": {"y": 1147, "x": 841}, 
        "node_data_attrs": {"groupid": "id_FW13-e052-7009-08", "rankgroupid": "rank_37"}
    }
]
```

with:

```
with gzip.GzipFile(args.file,'rb') as gzf:
    all_hovers = json.load(gzf)
```

How can I read out the node_data_attrs values?

```
for cords in all_hovers[userID]:
    x = cords["mouse_position"]["x"]
    y = cords["mouse_position"]["y"]
    viewport_x = cords["viewport_dimensions"]["width"]
    viewport_y = cords["viewport_dimensions"]["height"]
    data_attrs = cords["node_data_attrs"]["groupid"]
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opdracht2-3.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "opdracht2-3.py", line 66, in main
    print cords["node_data_attrs"]["groupid"]
KeyError: 'groupid'
```

That doesn't work for reading the data... any suggestions?

Comment: In your code, what is `all_hovers`? Can you post more of your json? I hardly see any relation between what your code is trying to get and the data you posted.

Comment: you ve that json data in file and you want to read it and get node_data_attrs ?

Comment: added the code that explains what all_hovers is :)

Comment: That should work as it is... I mean the code. The JSON is not valid

Comment: *That doesn't work* is **not** a problem description. **How** doesn't it work? Do you get exceptions? Not the data you expected? What *does* happen (full tracebacks please).

Comment: I corrected your 'sample' to at least be a valid JSON *snippet*. If your data doesn't look like that and is not part of a larger valid JSON file, you'll need to correct your input file first.

Comment: added the traceback :)

Comment: @user3289867: so perhaps **some** of your `node_data_attrs` objects do not have a `groupid` key? Your sample data does, but are you 100% certain *all* entries have that key?

Comment: No not all of them have... So how can I still get the data from those who have?

Comment: @user3289867, what does "get data" MEAN in that instance? What do you want to happen if there is no `cords["node_data_attrs"]["groupid"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine, it just appears that at least **some** of your data doesn't have a `groupid` key.

Use `.get()` to work around this:

```
for cords in all_hovers[userID]:
    x = cords["mouse_position"]["x"]
    y = cords["mouse_position"]["y"]
    viewport_x = cords["viewport_dimensions"]["width"]
    viewport_y = cords["viewport_dimensions"]["height"]
    data_attrs = cords["node_data_attrs"].get("groupid")
```

This sets `data_attrs` to `None` if the key is missing. You can set it to a different default by passing in a second argument to `dict.get()`:

```
    data_attrs = cords["node_data_attrs"].get("groupid", 'default value')
```

Comment: Graag gedaan, prettig weekend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following sequence of numbers inserted into an AVL tree, indicate if the insertion results in no-rotate, rotate right, rotate left, double rotate left, and double rotate right.

> 9,8,7,6,2,3,4,5,11,1,12,23,24

List the BST tree in level order if no rotations are  done:
Root: 
L1:
L2:
...

List the AVL tree in level order if rotations are  done:
For the toolbar, press `ALT+F10 (PC)` or `ALT+FN+F10 (Mac)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps. But if you can help wth this question with c++, using visual studios. Having trouble too